# Finding the inverse of $f(x) = x\sqrt{2+x^2}$

Tags: calculus, functions

For a function $f(x) = x\sqrt{2+x^2}$ find out if it's bijective and if so, find its inverse.

The function is surjective because $x^2 > 0:\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$. I'm having difficulties proving that the function is injective.

I tried the following: $$f(x) = f(y) \iff x\sqrt{2+x^2} = y\sqrt{2+y^2} \\ x^2(2+x^2) = y^2(2+y^2) \\ 2x^2+x^4 = 2y^2 + y^4$$

And well, I think I just made it more difficult for myself. I couldn't find any thread on MSE where one tried tackling such a specific problem.

Solution appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Factor it: $2x^2 + x^4 = 2y^2 + y^4  \to (y^2-x^2)(y^2+x^2 + 2) = 0$. Now use that $x^2+y^2 + 2 \geq 2$ so $y^2 = x^2$. Rule out $y=-x$ and your done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition $x^2\ge0$, which implies $2+x^2>0$ just tells you that the function is defined on $\mathbb{R}$, but not that it is surjective. For instance, the function
$$
g(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2+x^2}}
$$
is not surjective if considered as $g\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, because $0<g(x)\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ for all $x$.

If you're allowed to use calculus, surjectivity and injectivity follow from considering these facts:

1. $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=-\infty$
2. $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$
3. $\displaystyle f'(x)=\sqrt{2+x^2}+\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{2+x^2}}>0$

Therefore $f$ is increasing and assumes every real value.

Without calculus it's a bit more difficult. Let's try solving the equation
$$
y=x\sqrt{2+x^2}
$$
with respect to $x$. First we note that if $x<0$, then also $y<0$ and conversely. Now we can square:
$$
y^2=2x^2+x^4
$$
or
$$
x^4+2x^2-y^2=0
$$
that furnishes
$$
x^2=-1+\sqrt{1+y^2}
$$
(the other solution of the quadratic equation must be discarded, because it's negative). Thus we can write
$$
|x|=\sqrt{\sqrt{1+y^2}-1}
$$
and, remembering the consideration above, we have
$$
x=\begin{cases}
\sqrt{\sqrt{1+y^2}-1} & \text{if $y>0$}\\[2ex]
0 & \text{if $y=0$}\\[2ex]
-\sqrt{\sqrt{1+y^2}-1} & \text{if $y<0$}\\[1ex]
\end{cases}
$$
and this proves both surjectivity and injectivity, because the function has an inverse.

Answer (score 2):

What do you know about monotonous functions? Is this function (strictly) monotonous, and if yes, does this tell you something about injectivity?

Comment: Ahh, clever. I didn't even think about that. The function is strictly increasing. However, how would one go about solving this algebraically?

Comment: We assume that $x,y>0$, other cases are trivial (why?). We start after your last step; and factorize:
$x^4-y^4+2(x^2-y^2)=(x^2+y^2)(x^2-y^2)+2(x+y)(x-y)=(x-y)(3(x+y)+(x^2+y^2))=0$, and since the left factor cannot be $0$, we are finished.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Let $a=x^2 \geq 0$ and $b=y^2 \geq 0$. The equation reduces to $$2a+a^2=2b+b^2$$

Comment: Thank you, could you give me a hint on how to solve for $x$ in $y = x\sqrt{2+x^2}$; i.e. I want to find the inverse.

Comment: @XMLParsing Same way, square, set $a=x^2$ and solve for $a$. And when you get to the last step, you need to remember that $x$ and $y$ have the same sign, this information is lost when you square.

Comment: Hmm, is it okay if I ask on how to proceed with your answer to prove surjectivity. I've been sitting thinking about how I would proceed, but I just don't see it. How am I supposed to reduce that expression to $a=b$? Thank you if you do reply.

Comment: @XMLParsing There is no $b$ in surjectivity and no reduction to $a=b$. If you are talking about injectivity, move everything on one side and factor $a-b$. Then use $a,b \geq 0$.

Comment: @XMLParsing For surjectivity, after you square and sub $a=x^2$ you get $y^2=a(2+a)$. This is a quadratic in $a$, solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

To find the inverse let $y= f^{-1}(x)$ then since $f(f^{-1}(x)) = x$ we have

$$f(f^{-1}(x)) = x = y\sqrt{2+y^2}$$

which gives

$$x^2 = y^2(2+y^2)\to y^4 + 2y^2 - x^2 = 0$$

This is a quadratic equation in $y^2$: $(y^2)^2 + 2y^2 - x^2 = 0$ for which you can use the standard formula on. To determine which root to pick notice that $f^{-1}(0)=0$ and $\text{sign}(f^{-1}(x)) = \text{sign}(x)$.

Comment: (I think you want a 2 under the square root instead of 1.)

Comment: @user84413 Thanks!